# Explain the operations for this method using bitwise operators

Tags: php, error-handling, bitwise-operators

can someone please explain the bitwise logic behind this method? it takes a php error level and returns if it is fatal or not. id like to understand what exactly is occurring.

```
    public static function isLevelFatal($level)
    {
        $errors = E_ERROR;
        $errors |= E_PARSE;
        $errors |= E_CORE_ERROR;
        $errors |= E_CORE_WARNING;
        $errors |= E_COMPILE_ERROR;
        $errors |= E_COMPILE_WARNING;
        return ($level & $errors) > 0;
    }
```

Comment: Do you know how bitwise operators work and what bit masks are? If not, can you research that a bit on your own?

Comment: i tried i cant figure out what the equal sign does with the bar.

Comment: Well then, why don't you focus your question on that?

Comment: thats what i thought i was asking. maybe i didnt explain it clearly?

Comment: Not really. Your question sounds like you have absolutely no clue what bitwise operations are, when apparently you've only never encountered `|=`.

Answer (score 3):

`$foo |= $bar` is simply shorthand for `$foo = $foo | $bar`;
This, incidentally, works with many other operators, like `$foo += 42`.

So that code is equivalent to:

```
$errors = E_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_COMPILE_WARNING;
```

So it's building a bit mask of all fatal errors, and then tells you whether `$level` is in that bit mask.

Answer (score 1):

Writing this:

```
$errors = E_ERROR;
$errors |= E_PARSE;
$errors |= E_CORE_ERROR;
$errors |= E_CORE_WARNING;
$errors |= E_COMPILE_ERROR;
$errors |= E_COMPILE_WARNING;
```

Is the same as writing this:

```
$errors = E_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR;
```

Alternatively, written like this so the bitmask is obvious:

```
<?php
$errors = E_ERROR;
echo str_pad(decbin($errors), 10, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT) . "\n";
$errors |= E_PARSE;
echo str_pad(decbin($errors), 10, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT) . "\n";
$errors |= E_CORE_ERROR;
echo str_pad(decbin($errors), 10, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT) . "\n";
$errors |= E_CORE_WARNING;
echo str_pad(decbin($errors), 10, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT) . "\n";
$errors |= E_COMPILE_ERROR;
echo str_pad(decbin($errors), 10, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT) . "\n";
$errors |= E_COMPILE_WARNING;
echo str_pad(decbin($errors), 10, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT) . "\n";
```

Will produce this output:

```
         1
       101
     10101
    110101
   1110101
  11110101
```

It's just creating a bitmask a bit at a time. The comparison is then a bit comparison of whether the passed `$level` is in `11110101` e.g.:

```
  11110101 # the mask
         1 # E_ERROR in this? yes
        10 # E_WARNING in this? no
```

I.e. the intention is exactly the same as:

```
public static function isLevelFatal($level)
{
    return in_array(
        $level, 
        [
            E_ERROR,
            E_PARSE,
            E_CORE_ERROR,
            E_CORE_WARNING,
            E_COMPILE_ERROR,
            E_COMPILE_WARNING
    );
}
```